# What does it mean to have infinitely large set with lower density of 0?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I came across "[...] there are infinitely many noncototients [...] but we do not know if their lower density is positive"

First of all I am assuming by lower density the author is referring to asymptotic lower density. The main thing I am looking for is some type of intuition about what it means to have an infinite set with zero density.

Comment: The prime numbers have zero density in the positive integers because the ratio "(number of primes $\leq n)$ divided by $n$" approaches $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty.$ Same for perfect squares, cubes, fourth powers, etc. (In fact, these have a stronger type of density $0,$ since the ratios approach $0$ quicker than in the case of the prime numbers.) On the other hand, the multiples of $17$ do not have zero density in the positive integers. As for *lower density*, this means we only require the $\liminf$ (not the limit) to be zero. It's possible to have $\liminf = 0$ and $\limsup = 1.$

Comment: Consider the following sequence of positive integers: $1,$ $2,$ $\ldots,$ $10,$ [skip $89$ integers] $10^2,$ $10^2 + 1,$ $10^2 + 2,$ $\ldots,$ $10^3,$ [skip $8999$ integers] $10^4,$ $10^4 + 1,$ $10^4 + 2,$ $\ldots,$ $10^5,$ [skip $899999$ integers] $10^6,$ $10^6 + 1,$ $10^6 + 2,$ $\ldots,$ $10^7,$ [skip $89999999$ integers] $10^8,$ $10^8 + 1,$ $\ldots$ This sequence has lower density $0$ and upper density $1$ in the positive integers.